# Accepting an answer to a closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, accepted-answer

To my surprise I discovered that I can accept an answer to my question that has been closed.

I am not sure whether it is "good" or "bad", my question is whether it is an intended feature and if yes, what could be the reasons for having it.

Comment: Well -- you can also vote on answers to closed questions. So I guess this is intended behavior of the software.

Comment: "closing" only prevents new answers from appearing, it has no effect on pre-existing answers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when I downvote a question/answer and the question is closed, do I lose a rep-point? I noticed that usually when I do such downvotes I don't lose a point, but I haven't precisely seen at which point is the minus-one cost canceled (when the question is closed or when it's deleted?)